# Join between different data types

Tags: sql, join, lookup-tables

In a particular scenario I have a lookup table with MachineNumber (Varchar) and its MachineID (Int). In my transaction table I refer to the Machine number using lookup table's MachineID.

Requirement: Can I have the MachineID field type set as Varchar in the transaction table whereas retaining its type as Int in the lookup table? Reason, for some Machines the MachinNumber is not stored in the Lookup table and I need to store the actual MachineNumber provided by the user in the Transaction table itself and as the Machine number is alphanumeric I want to change the type of this referenced field from Int to Varchar.

In a nutshell in the transaction table the MachineID field should contain both MachineID (referenced from the lookup table) and actual Machine Number (provided by the user and stored directly here)

Question: Is it a good practice to have different types for these referenced fields or is it a common practice, what will be the effect on the queries with Join between these two tables?

Thanks,
Alind

Comment: What SQL dialect (Microsoft, Oracle, mySQL) and version are you using.

Comment: We are using MS SQL 2005 standard version.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, using natural data as the key is preferred, if of course you it is guaranteed to be present and unique in all cases.

In your case, if you can use the *actual* machine id (varchar), then do so, and make that the key for your lookups etc.

I will add that I once worked for a company that had EFTPOS terminals transacting with our server. We decided to use the convenient unique EFTPOS terminal ID, but we had problem when they broke down and were swapped out by a repair guy from the bank. The new terminal had a different ID, but to use was "the same" terminal. Our problems were compounded when the terminal was repaired and put back into the field at *another* client location - with the same original terminal id! This initially caused us no end of hassle. We ended up using an artificial id, and sotred the *current* physical terminal id as an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my dilemma is there can be similar MachineNumbers between different Machine groups so using MachineNumber as a key is not an option, second issue is there are chances that the MachineNumber will be edited later on, these are the reasons for using MachineID. Again my question is will it be advisable to have different data type fields (Int and Varchar) to link MachineID fields between two tables?

Comment: In that case, use an int as the primary key of your "machine" table, and store the text "machine number" as an attribute (normal column) of the "machine" table. Have all other tables use an int foreign key reference back to your "machine" table.